# Evaporation Formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus, approximation

I am currently working on a project that has been passed down several times, along the chain of responsibility. This project is develop a Calculator that, after entering set amount of data, will let us know how extreme the circumstances are and whether we need to inform that proper government agencies/entities.

Now, specifically, I am looking for a generalize formula to calculate Evaporation rate of Hazardous Substances. My main thought was to come up with an evaporation formula for water, then substitute density, vapor pressure, whatever else I would need, in order to get an approximation of what was spilled.

An Engineering student had given us some formulas but they don't look quite right, nor can I verify the legitimacy of the formulas.

Here are some of them:

General Evaporation Rate Formula
$\frac {(0.284 \cdot (\mathbf {Average\ windspeed})^{0.78} \cdot (\mathbf {molecular\ weight})^{0.667} \cdot (\mathbf {surface\ area}) \cdot (\mathbf {vapor\ pressure})}{(82.05 * (\mathbf {temperature\ in\ K})}$

Evaporation Rate from Berm
$\frac {(0.284 \cdot (\mathbf{Average\ windspeed})^{0.78} \cdot (\mathbf{molecular\ weight})^{0.667} \cdot (\mathbf{surface\ area}) \cdot (\mathbf{Surface\ Area}) \cdot (\mathbf{vapor\ pressure})}{(82.05 * (\mathbf{temperature\ in\ K}))}$

*****Surface Area Equations******
**Scenario 1:**
$l \cdot w = A$
$A - (\pi \cdot (\frac {\mathbf{Diameter\ of\ tank\ in\ berm}}{2})^2 \cdot (\mathbf{How\ many\ tanks\ in\ berm}))$
**Scenario 2**:If we have 3 tanks in the berm
$l \cdot w = A$
$A - (\pi \cdot ((\frac {\mathbf{Diameter\ of\ tank\ in\ berm}}{2})^2)) \cdot (\mathbf {Number\ of\ tanks\ in\ berm,\ of\ that\ diameter}))-\pi (\frac{(\mathbf{Diameter\ of\ tank\ in\ berm})}{2})^2 * (\mathbf {Number\ of\  tanks\ in\ berm,\ of\ that\ diameter}))- \pi(\frac{(\mathbf{Diameter\ of\ tank\ in\ berm})}{2})^2 \cdot (\mathbf {Number\ of\ tanks\ in\ berm,\ of\ that\ diameter}))$

Now this isn't pretty, so my apologies, but I am new to this section of forums.

If anyone could give me some insight or direction, that would be most appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: What is 'berm'? Also, you could look up [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/140607) for formatting

Comment: This doesn't seem like a very mathematical problem. It seems like either a modeling problem (if the relevant equations are not already available) or a pure engineering problem (if they are).

Comment: This does look strange in some ways.  Why inversely proportional to temperature?  What if there is no wind?  Vapor pressure measured where (for a hazardous material, one would hope there is very little vapor pressure of that material far away)?  But you should ask engineers, not mathematicians.

Comment: @shardulc Berm is a something that can contain a liquid or solid of some sorts. think of it as Secondary Containment

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments thus far, I will post this in an engineering section as well.

Comment: @Skemper That'll be cross posting might as well flag it and migrate it.

Comment: @Sigma6RPU Not sure how to do that. Still rather new to these forums.

Comment: In its current form, it wouldn't be accepted on [engineering.se], "some insight and direction" makes it automatically too broad. If you want to know a) how to determine the evaporation rate, and b) whether the formulae you got are correct, that would be on-topic there. If so, we can edit and then migrate the question.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks for that. However I can re-word this in order to get more information about my problem, I am happy to oblige.

Comment: @Skemper Topically, it belongs on [engineering.se], not here, so edit the version over there. As far as I can tell, you want to know how to determine the evaporation rate, resp. what the correct formulae are. Ask that, explicitly. Make it focused, don't ask for "insights and directions", ask for facts.